# Django objects.get for loop issue

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-queryset

I'm trying to do a for loop 1 through 100 into a primary key (pk) for an objects.get in django. I keep getting `a matching query does not exist.` I assume the django isn't reading the output as an int.

```
def f_factory(i):
    def f(offset):
      nonlocal i
      i += offset
      return i 

for i in range(3):
    an = djangonote.objects.get(pk=i)
    print(an.id)
```

Comment: Did you check if all the PKs exist? And did you consider using one QuerySet instead of many queries?

Comment: `for(1, 100)` instead of `for(3)`. But it is *not* a good idea to work with an iterator to fetch the items, since items can be removed and this will result in the fact that for some `i`, there is no `djangonote` for that primary key.

Comment: Figured out the issue. Just ran an all query to grab data then parsed